# bash: write list of file names in a file with additional texts

Tags: bash, glob, ls

I want to write some text to a file for each filename in a folder. Something like this:

```
echo "file $(ls *.png) \n duration 0.12" >  test.txt
```

However, this code just adds `file` at the beginning and `\n duration 0.12` at the end of the file and the list of files in between, while I want something like this:

```
  file 1.png
  duration 0.12
  file 2.png 
  duration 0.12
```

The file must actually be in the format of ffmpeg concat demuxer.

I know that I might be able to use a loop. However, I don't know if there is a shorter command or if the loop is as efficient as a `ls` or another linux command?

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: Are you actually trying to use the **ffmpeg** `concat demuxer`?

Comment: @MarkSetchell yeah that's my aim.

Comment: You can use `printf "%s\nduration 0.12\n" *.png`

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks, that could be an answer! however I guess `printf "file %s\nduration 0.12\n"  *.png`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that fairly simply like this using `bash` *"globbing"*:

```
printf "file %s\nduration 0.12\n" *.png
```

**Sample Output**

```
file a.png
duration 0.12
file alpha.png
duration 0.12
file b.png
duration 0.12
file bg.png
duration 0.12
```

Note that, if you want them in a specific order, you can do things like this:

```
printf "file %s\nduration 0.12\n" d*.png t*.png p*.png
```

Answer (score 3):

With GNU find:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.png" -type f -printf "file %f\nduration 0.12\n"
```

---

See: `man find`

Comment: That's what I meant :)

Comment: @Cyrus You're welcome to edit my suggestion in the comments into your answer as it's only a simplification of your original concept

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Thank you. I suggest posting your comment above as a separate reply, as it uses globbing of bash.

Comment: Please note that this may not always generate the expected output. Globs like `*` expand in a sorted order while `find` does not. OP didn't explicitly ask for a sorted list, however, I have the feeling that the order of files could be important here (it looks like OP wants to generate an animation from a list of images).

Comment: @Socowi: Yes, if Ahmad wanted to have the output in a certain order, then this solution would not be suitable.